# Unable to start server of Django through command prompt

Tags: django

[image]When I type " python manage.py runserver " it show this in the picture

how to fix this problem?
Once I've started the server but now it shows this error.

Comment: where is the error? you can paste it as code.

Comment: There is no picture showing the error.Type it in as a code block

Comment: I think you forgot to put the picture.. we need more details to help you.

Comment: Now it's uploaded.

Comment: Please check your  ../Stifler/urls.py at line 17

Comment: I've changed that line to "" from django.urls import path "" then it works. Thanks a lot...